# Motion foward is stoping the character's fall

Tags: game-engine, physics, logic-bricks

Ok I searched this question and seems nobody is talking abount this.

I set up a acceleration system with bricks of **"Servo Control Motion"** being actaveted by an property whith number that is kind of a **velocimeter**. I push the accel button and it **add** to the property and **subtract** when not pressed. The higher the number of property activate the **Stronger "Motion Actuator"**, (corrent have 10 motion actuators in sequence each stronger than de last)

I Got that problem when the character is in mid air, while accelerating he's falling very slowly, stop the motion and he will fall normaly. It was actualy occuring with the **"simple motion actuator" in "linear velocity"** so a read in the manual that the **"servo controler"** fixes that problem. I tested it alone and seemed to work fine while falling. but after that I put it in sequence to simulate acceleration of a cart the problem of the slow fall was back.
I don't know if i changed other option in phisics of the character to be hapening this.

I cold set up an sensor to stop all te Motions actuator while he's in mid air, but it will stop the motion foward when he's falling, and i want to keep the foward velocity while in air.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used logic bricks since 2008, and I quickly moved into python scripting for more flexible control, but I believe the issue you are seeing is from your Servo Control attempting to match all of the velocities, instead of the axis you expect it to effect.

I assume Z is up, and that your servo control is set to zero. The servo control tries to reach zero velocity on the z axis, **effectively resisting gravity!**

The XYZ limit buttons below the Linear Velocity field actually limit the force the servo can apply to reach the target linear velocity. If you turn on the Z limit button and leave the min/max values at zero, then the servo control will have no power over your Z axis.

Good luck!